# How to switch between $application_folder in ci?

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

I am developing an app that has two application under codeigniter!

My folders is look like this:

```
application
   |- admin
   |- site
```

I want to switch between this, Also i know that the configuration for this setting is: `$application_folder`

Actually i want to know how to switch between (under what condition)

`$application_folder = 'application/admin';`

```
and

$application_folder = 'application/site';
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lD0zrW1o_4 , and see if it helps.

Comment: this should give you a idea http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter you need to create a folder on the main directory named admin and add a new index.php also on user guide http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html